# How to separate player state on shared object?

Tags: data-structure, state, quadtree, planet

I'm new to game dev and I'm learning about quadtrees for planet rendering. I'm curious on how do I separate player state with quadtrees. For example I have a ship A that's getting close to a planet, and the quadtrees for that planet are showing the correct levels and resolution for player A the closer he gets. How would I keep player B who is behind player from seeing the quadtrees activated by player A?

Player A and B are both on the same server communicating by WebSockets

Comment: Are player A and player B on the same computer, rendering with the same graphics context?

Comment: @Romen excuse my last comment I just realized what you meant. A and B are both on the same server communicating by WebSockets

Comment: Shouldn't anything used for rendering exist on both player's machines independently, not on the server? Does the server actually need to know anything about the rendering?